# How can I round to certain # of decimal places in data-driven field display?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, data-driven-pages

Can I round the value being shows in a textbox that is provided through Data Driven Pages?

In the example below I have a SHape_Length value I want to display on the map but even though I have sent the number of decimal places to show in the table, that is not being transferred to the table.

[image: I want to make Length value in text box match Shape_Length value in table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I had changed the displayed decimal places on the original source attribute table, but the table gets joined to another table and that was the value being displayed, so once I changed the decimal places on the joined table, it displays properly.
[image]

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a bit with some explanation where you found the settings and what you changed?

Comment: Sure thing, in the attribute table's field properties I clicked on the "Numeric" button and in that window I changed the displayed number of decimal places/alignment characters.  However, those settings are specific to the ORIGIN table, not the joined TARGET table, so once I changed the same attribute field properties in that target table's joined version  of the attribute, the number displayed properly.